# How to Update a Pull Request on Github

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a feature branch on git and I set is as a Pull Request.

I've made 3 commits to the feature branch but the latest commits are not showing up in the pull request page.

Is there a way to update my pull request to show the latest commits from the feature branch?

Comment: Usually new commits are appended to the Pull Request automatically. Are you sure you have pushed all commits to github?

Answer (score 0):

Check first your `git status`

- you must be on the feature branch and not on a detached HEAD
- your branch should be ahead of origin/feature branch
- the remote feature branch should be the one from which the PR has been initiated.